# Eclipse Ctrl+H project search display format

Tags: eclipse, search, format, project

Is there a way to have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> *Eclipse* project searches display in flat format instead of in a tree structure? Clicking through the results is tedious and inefficient.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure the version of Eclipse that folks are running, but in Indigo I had to go to the "Menu" to see the "Show as List" option.

[image: Search Results Config]

Answer (score 3):

There are many option to view the search result.

See at the top bar of the result console. There are `[+]` expand all `[-]` collaps all and many grouping options. These will make you filter through results quickly.

[image]

When you select Filter by File, you will see all files (flat! I guess that's what you wanted) that have your search result.