# selecting multiple files in eclipse navigator/package explorer

Tags: eclipse

I want to select all files that end with "grid" in eclipse navigator/package explorer in one shot, so that I can do a svn commit at once.

Is there a way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Did U tried search function ???

Answer (score 2):

Press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to open search dialog. Go to File search tab in that.

Leave `containing text` text box blank and in `File name pattern` text box enter `*grid`. Press <kbd>Search</kbd> button.

In search view select `show as list` option refer screen shot from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8794725/1391924). Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all files. Right click on the selection and go to team menu item to commit.